# A question about current and Dirac measure

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

$0$ can be seen as a divisor of $\mathbb{C}$, and the current $[0]$ is defined as $[0](\varphi)=\varphi(0)$. Why is this reasonable?

Comment: ...what do you find unreasonable about it?

Comment: Is there some other definition of this current? Why is the Dirac measure? Is it just a definition or can we get it from the Stokes formula?

Comment: I've given the usual definition of current in my answer, and explained how oriented submanifolds give rise to currents, and in particular the Dirac distribution. Nowhere did we need Stokes formula, but it can be used to define an 'exterior derivative' of currents.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{D}^p(X)$ denote the space of compactly-supported smooth $p$-forms on a smooth manifold $X$ (topologized in the same way as the space of distributions), then a **$p$-current** is defined to be a continuous linear functional $\mathcal{D}^p(X) \to \mathbb{R}$.

An important class of currents arise from the oriented $p$-submanifolds $S \subset X$ (i.e. objects over which a $p$-form can be integrated): the current $[S]$ associated to the $p$-submanifold $S$ is defined to be the functional
$$
\eta \mapsto [S](\eta):=\int_S \eta.
$$

Furthermore, the $0$-currents are just linear functionals $\mathcal{D}^0(X) = \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c (X) \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. distributions on $X$. Those $0$-currents that arise from $0$-submanifolds can be easily described; for example, the current associated to the point $\{ P \} \subset X$ is given by 
$$[P](\eta) = \eta(P), \hspace{2mm} \eta \in \mathcal{D}^0(X) = C^{\infty}_{c}(X),
$$ as integration over a point just picks out the value of the integrand at that point. That is, the $0$-current $[P]$ is precisely the Dirac delta distribution on $X$ at the point $P$.

*Edit*: it is interesting to note how Stokes theorem behaves in this context: it says that for a $p$-dimensional oriented submanifold $S \subset X$ and $\eta \in \mathcal{D}^{p-1}(X)$,
$$
[S](d\eta) = \int_S d\eta = \int_{\partial S} \eta = [\partial S](\eta).
$$
This has a continuous extension to an operator $\partial \colon [\mathcal{D}^{p}(X)]' \to [\mathcal{D}^{p-1}(X)]'$ on currents, which is often called the boundary operator.